# Problema al obtener dato de un Item del List view, cuando el Adapter es llenado por un Cursor

Tags: android, sqlite

En mi actividad principal `mainActivity` muestro un `listview` de los datos de mi base de datos local en `SQlite` consultados a través de una clase `DataBaseHelper`, donde creó la base de datos y una clase `SQLcontrolle` donde esta el metodo cursor `readData` que es finalmente la consulta en si, la consulta y el despliegue de la misma se efectúan perfectamente.

Hora lo que intento es que al momento que le den click al ITEM   se muestre un mensaje con el `ID` o la posición o en su defecto el "ID"  correspondiente al registro en la lista, esto es lo que tengo hasta ahora de código:

> Al darle click al ITEM me lanza Se ha detenido la aplicacion 
>   del registro seleccionado:

**MainActivity.java** (Actualizado 28-02)

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    dbcon = new SQLController(this);
    dbcon.open();
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);


    Cursor cursor = dbcon.readData();
    String[] from = new String[] { DatabaseHelper.IDs,    DatabaseHelper.MSG};
    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.ids, R.id.msg};


    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
            MainActivity.this, R.layout.list_item, cursor, from, to);
    Firm = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.firma);

    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
            int itemPosition     = position;
            String  itemValue    = (String)   lv.getItemAtPosition(position);
            // Show Message
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Position :"+itemPosition+"  ListItem : " +itemValue , Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }
    });
```

.
.
La clase SQLController donde esta el metodo cursor Read Data

**SQLControler.java**

```
public class SQLController {

private DatabaseHelper DatabaseHelper;
private Context ourcontext;
private SQLiteDatabase database;

public SQLController(Context c) {
    ourcontext = c;
}

public SQLController open() throws SQLException {
    DatabaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(ourcontext);
    database = DatabaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;

}

//Getting Cursor to read data from table
public Cursor readData() {
    String[] allColumns = new String[] { DatabaseHelper.IDs, DatabaseHelper.MSG };
    Cursor c = database.query(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME, allColumns, null,
            null, null, null, DatabaseHelper.IDs+" DESC",null);
    if (c != null) {
        c.moveToFirst();
    }
    return c;
}
```

Y por ultimo DatabaseHelper donde creo la base de datos:

**DatabaseHelper.java**

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "GCM";
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "newsTable";
public static final String IDs = "_id";
public static final String MSG = "MESSAGE";
public static final String FIRMA = "firma";
public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "(" + IDs + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + MSG + " STRING, " + FIRMA + " STRING)");
}
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}
```

Cualquier ayuda, sugerencia y comentario se los agradesco de antemano, gracias por su atención

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creo que usted esta obteniendo el ultimo registro porque usted usa "DESC" y despues hace -> `String ids= cursor.getString(0);` y este no veo que cambie en ningun momento siempre se consulta sobre 0, y este es el ultimo registro por "desc" | [cursor.getString ()](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getString(int))

> 

---

Yo no se como usted esta manejando el `Checkbox`, en relacion con el ListView, pero usted podria tratar de obtener la posicion con algo asi:

```
final ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView01);

lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> myAdapter, View myView,
                              int myItemInt, long mylng) {

        int sList = lv.getItemAtPosition(myItemInt);

        /*   Aqui puede obtener el item selecionado 
         *  y usarlo para mostrar el mensaje que le
         *  corresponda en lugar de usar el 0 pasandolo
         *  de alguna manera
         *
         *  Nota: Puede que tenga que tener en cuenta la position que le 
         * corresponde a cada item y si esta es la misma para la consulta
         * a la BD porque usted usa desc y no se si lo item se iran 
         * añadiendo de forma dinamica, y tenga que hacer alguna
         * operacion matematica para que la position que obtenga
         * corresponda con el id de la consulta, espero me entienda,
         * aunque es posible que le funcione bien de la forma que esta,
         * pero se lo dejo como observacion
         */ 
      }                 
});
```

---

Con este metodo puede consultar la posicion del item selecionado y usarlo en  de alguna manera `String ids= cursor.getString(position);`

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, 
                        int position, long arg3) {      
}
```

list.setClickable(true);

http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html

http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/widget/ListView.html

---

Como digo yo no se de que manera tiene implementado el listView, esto es solo una idea al ver lo que muestra, pero igual (que no se si esta si lo tiene asi) puede poner el checkbox dentro del holder:

Algo asi:

```
holder.name = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
   convertView.setTag(holder);

    holder.name.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {

     public void onClick(View v) {  

      CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v ;  

      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                     "Clicked on Checkbox: " + cb.getText() +
                     " is " + cb.isChecked(), 
                     Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

     /*
      *Implementar aqui el manejo del cursor
      */
     }
```

Pero solo es una idea le dejo un [link completo sobre](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/07/android-listview-checkbox-example.html) la forma anterior, la puede mirar y determinar si le es mas comoda o no, pues solo usted y dios sabe que esta haciendo ahora mismo y cual es su idea.

Espero le ayude.

Comment: Gracias por responder Angel Angel, al usar el lv.setOnItemClickListener me y darle click al item se cierra la app y lanza el mensaje de que se ha detenido la aplicacion, ya actualice el post arriba, saludos y gracias de antemano

Comment: este es el mensaje de error java.lang.ClassCastException: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor cannot be cast to java.lang.String

Comment: @JESUSESPINOSA le comente que tratara de crear otra pregunta porque si ahora le contesto a esta, la pregunta original se pierde y si sigue añadiendo cambios a la pregunta puede que no sea util para algun usuario que busque por el primer error que tenia espero me entienda y no se lo tome a mal, formule otra pregunta con los datos para ella y yo me encargo de poner la pregunta suya como estaba entes de los cambios que hizo Saludos

Answer (score 3):

Jesus, recuerda que tu `Adapter` fue llenado por un Cursor, así que tu problema es que estas realizando una incorrecta conversión a String:

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                            int position, long id) {
        ...
        ...
        String  itemValue    = (String)   lv.getItemAtPosition(position);
        ...
        ...
    }
});
```

Debe ser:

```
 Cursor  itemValue    =  (Cursor)  lv.getItemAtPosition(position);
  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Position :"+itemPosition+"  ListItem : " +itemValue.getString(0) , Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
```

Siendo `itemValue` un `Cursor`, puedes acceder mediante el indice a sus campos: `itemValue.getString(0), itemValue.getString(1),itemValue.getString(2)`,.... etc.

Comment: es lo que tu dices o eso creo yo pero, le estaba diciendo que creara una nueva pregunta para ello porque esta cambiando la pregunta original y si alguien tiene un error parecido al que al inicial sera mas dificil de encontrar. Elenasys dile que haga otra pregunta y tu le respondes ahi si no te importa creo que seria mejor. Saludos

Comment: y si alguien tiene un error como el que usted responde, nadie podra encontrarlo en esta respuesta con el titulo de la pregunta original o sera mas dificil. Saludos

Comment: @AngelAngel, de hecho la pregunta la marcaron como demasiado Amplia jejeje. Bueno al menos se respondío su duda.

Comment: si jaja, no si lo que usted responde creo que es la solucion para el problema que le sucede ahora, pero le dije que creara una nueva pregunta pero no se que ira a hacer, yo apuesto ahora por su respuesta jaja pero, espero haber que hace el usuario si crea una nueva para hacer roll de la pregunta para dejarla como estaba antes. Saludos

Comment: Creo que es suficiente con la misma pregunta pero he cambiado el titulo. =)

Comment: jaja no me cambies el titulo que si no me votan en contra mi respuesta jaja espera haber si el usuario crea una nueva

Comment: si miras las ediciones yo respondi a la numero 2, y ahora esta por 6 ediciones. Saludos

Comment: muchas gracias por su ayuda, ambos son unos genios, ya esta funcionando solo cabe agregar que el toask sería ListItem : " +itemValue.getString(0)